# Yum gets broken in Centos 7 while being updated

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade, rpm

I recently tried to update my Centos7. While being updated, I lost power and later on yum does not work. It looks like the script for yum and dependencies gets broken.

I have tried couple of options mentioned in [Remove yum manually](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=72502):

Placed the packages mentioned below and used: `rpm --install --force *.rpm`

```
yum-3.4.3-163.el7.centos.noarch
yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-10.el7.x86_64
yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch
yum-plugin-priorities-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch
```

This did not solve the problem. The error messages are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/yum", line 4, in <module>
import yum
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
import rpmsack
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 38, in <module>
import yum.depsolve
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 57, in <module>
flags = {"GT": rpm.RPMSENSE_GREATER,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RPMSENSE_GREATER'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from incompatible `rpm-python`. Put that on the list and it should work.

And then you can run `yum-complete-transaction` which will finish the incomplete previous transaction.